# How to fake a file merge after making changes?

Tags: git

I have pasted another version of a file in my project, it has additions and deletions. I want to fake a merge into current committed version so that I could see and resolve conflicts easier than comparing the files by eye.

How can I initiate a merge of a modified file (working tree) into HEAD version of the same file?

```
config/routes.rb # (1) commited version HEAD
config/routes.rb # (2) modified version in working tree
```

I have pasted the (2) `config/routes.rb` from a file that my friend sent me into my existing routes file (1).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to truly "merge" two files, you need a "base" version from which they were both derived.  Otherwise, the computer can't tell the difference between an addition in one file and a deletion in the other, so it can't tell which version is newer and can't make any automatic changes (i.e., every change would be a conflict).  For example:

```
file1:
...
here is a line
this line was added in file 1, or was it deleted in file 2?
here's the next line
...

file2:
...
here is a line
here's the next line
...
```

Without a base file, there's no way to tell what happened here, so it's not clear if `file1` or `file2` is the correct version.

If you have a base version checked into git, say at commit `123abc` then the easiest way to do it is:

- make sure your tree is clean (i.e., move the new version out of the way and re-checkout your HEAD version)
- do a `git branch topic_merge_friends_changes 123abc` to create a temporary branch at the commit containing the base version
- check out the branch: `git checkout topic_merge_friends_changes` -- note that this can be combined with the previous step using the `-b` flag with `checkout`
- **now**, move your new file into place and `git commit` it
- switch back to master: `git checkout master`
- and `git merge topic_merge_friends_changes`

Alternatively, you can skip the committing and merging and instead copy the base version (call it `base.txt`) and the two later versions (`mine.txt` and `friends.txt`) somewhere and then run `git merge-file mine.txt base.txt friends.txt` to merge your friend's changes into `mine.txt` without actually generating and commits or new branchs.

Finally, if you don't have a base file, the best you can do is manually examine and edit a diff between the two files.  You can either

- write the output of `git diff` to a file and manually edit the result to get the file you want (and of course you'll need to remove the indenting that diff adds to the areas where the files agree)
- use a visual diff tool -- Emacs has a nice visual diff mode (e.g., `M-x ediff-merge-files`) that let's you view each change side-by-side and select the version you want with a keystroke, and many other editors will have similar facilities

Comment: Hi again, any way to merge a file from stash? .. when I do git stash pop, it says the file already exists, so I need to try and merge it.